# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found**

Tags: php, laravel

I tried with all of these commands but it doesn't work

```
composer update --no-scripts
cd bootstrap/cache/->rm -rf *.php
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Which file does give the error?

Comment: welcome to so, your question looks incomplete, we suggest take a look at [How to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)